# Being vs Getting

Tags: word-meaning

Does "being" in the following sentence mean "getting"?

▪ An example of "best-case" is the outcome of an eye surgery **being** perfect vision.

Comment: No.  There's a large difference between the outcome *being* something and the outcome *getting* something.  It's quite difficult for me to imagine an outcome receiving or obtaining anything at all, let alone when the thing obtained is *perfect vision*.  It makes more sense to go in the opposite direction: the outcome might *give* perfect vision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand your question because I am also hoping for perfect vision following eye surgery in a few weeks. However, "being" does not equal "getting." As the person receiving the surgery, and hopefully ending up with better vision, it will feel like getting something. However, the way I understand the optical nerve and apparatus that enables us to see light and images, it's like a window. One does not "go and get" a light; the light is already there waiting to get in.

For example, a window lets in light only if nothing is in front of it, like a shutter or blind or tall piece of furniture or tree or if it's painted over or...the list goes on. Likewise, the eye and optical nerve. Removing the blockade or barrier from in front of the window does not "give" light because the light has always been outside the window waiting to come in; removal lets light in. A good outcome is a brightly-lit room. Likewise, a best-case outcome of an eye surgery is perfect vision.

Doctors are obligated to tell of the risks and advantages of surgery. Perfect vision may not be guaranteed but it is an example of a "best case outcome." That is how I understand your quote, given what little there is of it. If this is not right, I suggest you add a bit more to your question to provide a better context for what is going on.

**Summary**

*Being* =/= *getting*. However, that quote means that the person undergoing eye surgery may expect to have perfect vision as a best case outcome. DISCLAIMER: I may be wrong. Check with your doctor to be sure this is the correct interpretation.

Comment: Thanks @Sarah. Actually it wasn't any doctor's advice. I took that sentence from an online English dictionary.